# File counter in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to coding and i'm trying to display a counter on screen that simply displays a number for how many files are in a certain folder and will change as the file count changes.

ideally it would be the number without a background (similar to a splash screen)  but i think thats far too ambitious at the mo!

as i said i'm new so have no idea where to start, so as much info as possibly is greatly appreciated
 thanks

Comment: Google for `get files in directory c#`. You will find `Directory.GetFiles`, which is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Just use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to get notified when something in your foler changed. Than you can count your file over the [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Just use `GetFiles` and display the length of the array which `GetFiles` returns.

Comment: A good example for the above.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx